# How to filter for first occurrence of record?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I have a Daily table in Teradata. On any given month, we can have about 500 clients (about 20 added a month) that meet the criteria below.

I built a query to pull data the 1st occurrence where the criteria was met. I was able to run the code successfully BUT ran into a problem I can't seem to fix.

```
SELECT MyFakeDate, MyFakeAccount

Row_Number() Over (Partition By MyFakeAccount ORDER BY MyFakeDate) AS ROW_N

FROM MyFakeTable

WHERE FakeField = 'Y' and MyFakeDate Betweem TRUNC(Current_Date - Extract(Day FROM Current_Date),'Month' And Last_Day(Trunc(Current_Date - Extract(Day From Current_Date),'Month')) Qualify Row_Number() OVER (Partition By MyFakeAccount ORDER BY MyFakeDate) = 1;
```

My results should have total records for July that met the criteria - and the total records that met the criteria in August. The query I have looks at July and August and combines the 520 records instead of giving me separate record sets for July (500 records) and another set for August (520).

Comment: Add `, trunc(MyFakeDate, 'month')` to the PARTITION BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT MyFakeDate, MyFakeAccount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyFakeAccount, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MyFakeDate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MyFakeDate) ORDER BY MyFakeDate) AS ROW_N FROM MyFakeTable WHERE FakeField = 'Y' AND MyFakeDate BETWEEN TRUNC(Current_Date - INTERVAL '2' MONTH, 'MONTH') + INTERVAL '1' DAY AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(Current_Date - INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 'MONTH')) QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyFakeAccount, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MyFakeDate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MyFakeDate) ORDER BY MyFakeDate) = 1;`